# Relative Precision of Android's GPS

Tags: android, gps, precision

[I know that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567443/how-accurate-is-android-gps) the absolute precision of position detection for gps hardware isn't that accurate.

But assume that I have two androids and they are syncing each other at one place. In which precision (horizontal area) can I predict the other android position if the devices don't walk away too much (e.g. 1km) ?

Would this as bad as several meters? Or could I increase the precision in a different way when I have two or more androids in an area of 1km^2? A precision of ~10cm would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to improve precision of Android's GPS: [take a look here on how to obtain the user location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) via GPS, Cell-ID or WI-FI